# InputBindig не работает во вложенном View. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Есть главное окно - **MainWindow**. В него вложена **View**. И в эту **View** вложена ещё одна **ChildView**.
Приложение сделано по паттерну MVVM.

Как это выглядит: (**MainWindow**)

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:RootVM />
</Window.DataContext>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
```

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SubstationDirectory.V.SubstationEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SubstationDirectory.V"
         xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:SubstationDirectory.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" x:Name="RootElem">

<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding UpdateSubstation}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>

<Grid>
    <local:Alert Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=RootElem, Path=DataContext.UpdateAlert}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibilityFromObjectIsNull}, ConverterParameter=false}" />
</Grid>
```

**ChildView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SubstationDirectory.V.Alert"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SubstationDirectory.V"
         xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:SubstationDirectory.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="RootElem">

    <UserControl.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding MainAction}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
</UserControl>
```

### Задача

Нужно привязать кнопку Enter к команде **ChildView**.

Как видно, я попытался сделать это при помощи `InputBindings`. Но это не сработало. Во **View** сделана привязка тоже. Но там все работает.

### Вопрос

Как сделать, чтобы привязка к клавише в **ChildView** заработала?

Comment: Это зависит от того, какой контрол в фокусе, наверное. Ваша View может получать фокус вообще?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да дело в фокусе. Спасибо! Не подскажите как можно установить фокус на контрол после того как его `Visiblity стал равен `Visible`  в рамках MVVM?

Comment: Через ковертер?

Comment: Ну фокус это, по идее, чисто вьюшная задача. VM об этом ничего знать не должна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что **ChildView** не получала фокус.